# Modifying code to get recent commented posts above older post

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, post, while-loop

I am trying to get this work, but it's not entirely working. This is how I currently query my posts:

```
<?php 
    // the query
    $the_query = new WP_Query(  array( 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); 
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
    ?>
        <!-- pagination here -->
        <!-- the loop -->
        <?php 
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
        ?>                          
            <li data-href="<?php $zlink = get_the_permalink(); echo preg_replace("#/$#im", '', $zlink);?>">
                <div>
                    <a class="button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </div>
```

What I am trying to achieve, is the following:

1. **Show recently commented post on top of posts that have a newer publish date...**
2. If a blog-post has a comment, regardless of how old that blog-post is, I want that blog-post above a newer blog-post, if that newer one has no update (meaning: no recent comments).

I started by showing the recently commented posts on top (see below), but this totally neglects the fact that there are posts without comments and I can't find a way to combine both and show them in one list.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
    'status' => 'approve',
    'number' => 6,
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
$comments = get_comments($args);

foreach($comments as $comment) : $count++;

        $post_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'p' => $comment->comment_post_ID,
            'posts_per_page' => 1
            );

        $posts = get_posts($post_args);

        foreach($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);

            the_title();
        endforeach;

endforeach;
?>
```

Could someone help?

Comment: The query you are using shows the latest comments? what issue do you have exactly Please explain?

Comment: Can you explain your sorting criteria explicitly please?  Example: If a blog-post has a comment, regardless of how old that blog-post is, I want that blog-post above a newer blog-post, if that newer one has no comments.

Comment: Exactly, @pendo. That's the only thing I'd like. So you could have 1. old-post-while-has-most-recent-comment-among all-posts 2. newest post 3. old-post-and-not-recently-commented (not before newest post date) and so on...

Comment: Can you check the solution I posted and see if that meets your needs?

Comment: I checked it, @pendo. Please see my reaction below your answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below creates an empty array, adds all the posts with comments to that array.  It then adds all the posts without comments.  Finally, it sorts them by the comment date or the post date, depending on whether that post had any comments or not

```
//create an array to stuff all your posts in
$arrAllPosts = array();

$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',  //show only posts (not pages, etc)
    'comment_count'     => array(   //pass it an array
        'value'     => 1,           //value is 1, with compare means greater than or equal to 1
        'compare'   => '>='
    ),
    'posts_per_page'    => -1       //gimme all of them
);
$postsWithComments = new WP_Query($args);


while($postsWithComments->have_posts()) {$postsWithComments->the_post();
    //get the comments for this post
    $comments = get_comments(array(
        'post_id'   => get_the_ID(),    //pass the post ID
        'orderby'   => 'comment_date',  //tell it to sort by the comment date, so you only get the latest
        'number'    => 1                //just get the latest
    ));
    foreach($comments as $comment) { //we're only looping this once, since there is only one
        $arrAllPosts[] = array(
            'dateToSortBy'  => $comment->comment_date,  //we'll use comment date to sort by later, instead of the post date
            'the_post_obj'  => $post                    //add the global post object, which is currently set to the current post
        );
    }
}
//now we get the posts with no comments
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',  //Only posts (not pages, etc)
    'comment_count'     => 0,       //Posts with no comments only
    'posts_per_page'    => -1       //gimme all of them
);

$postsNoComments = new WP_Query($args); //run it

while($postsNoComments->have_posts()) {$postsNoComments->the_post();    //loop it
    $arrAllPosts[] = array(
        'dateToSortBy'  => $post->post_date,  //we'll use the post date to sort by
        'the_post_obj'  => $post            //add the global post object, which is currently set to the current post
    );

}

function date_compare($a, $b) { //create a custom function to sort the array by the date of the post or the date of the comment
    $tmA = strtotime($a['dateToSortBy']);   //convert to time
    $tmB = strtotime($b['dateToSortBy']);   //convert to time
    return ($tmA < $tmB)?true:false;
}
usort($arrAllPosts, 'date_compare');

//Display the title for each post, from the sorted list
foreach($arrAllPosts as $curPost) { 
    $post = $curPost['the_post_obj'];   //make this the global post object
    setup_postdata($post);              //setup the data
    echo "<a href='" . get_the_permalink() . "'>" . get_the_title() . "</a>";
}
```

Comment: Pendo, wow! Okay, one by one: so this replaces which code? How do I loop with my list items exactly?

Comment: I added a foreach loop that iterates over your posts and outputs the title, just like your example code.  Does that help make it clear?

Comment: Wow! Almost there, pendo... the issue is that there is no link. The posts are just plain text (titles), but no URL or hyperlink to link to them. Could you check that as well?

Comment: That is how your original code had it, so I recreated it.  Are you looking for the_permalink(); ?  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink

Comment: Hmm. I did however spit out the permalink/url anyway (see also code, it's there). What exactly would I need to change to get the links to work now? Where do I add the permalink?

Comment: I added the_permalink(); to my code.  Does that help get you what you need?

Comment: Alright, so I think you misunderstood (or I didn't tell properly). I just want the title of the post to be linked to the post. That's what I mean with the permalink...

Comment: Pendo, you still there?

Comment: I've updated the code to reflect that.  You should look at the different functions for get_the_title() and get_the_permalink() to understand what you're doing as this is a very simple change.